# Powershell Selenium select a dropdown menu with FindElementByCssSelector

Tags: powershell, selenium, drop-down-menu

I'm using Selenium to attempt to open a webpage, enter login credentials, click logon button, click new change control option, then enter my name and select it from a dropdown.  I have it all working until the dropdown portion.  Here's a pic of my recording:

[Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdSOb.jpg)

So here's the code I'm using (I'm using the Selenium module because I thought it would make life easier) I have my username and password obfuscated just so it doesn't show up in cleartext

```
$LandeskUrl = "The site I'm going to is here"

$Driver = Start-SeChrome
Enter-SeUrl $LandeskUrl -Driver $Driver

###Logon screen

#user name
$UserName = Find-SeElement -Driver $Driver -Id "Ecom_User_ID"
Send-SeKeys -Element $UserName -Keys $passCreds.UserName

#password field
$Password = Find-SeElement -Driver $Driver -Id "Ecom_User_Password"
Send-SeKeys -Element $Password -Keys $thePass

#click logon button
$LogonButton = Find-SeElement -Drive $Driver -Id "logonButton"
Invoke-SeClick -Element $LogonButton

##Landesk screen

#select "Create New Change Control"
$NewCCR = Find-SeElement -Drive $Driver -Id "shortcutItem_4765085e-1b8b-44a1-a896-883efb86f151"
Invoke-SeClick -Element $NewCCR

#select user field and type name
$User = Find-SeElement -Drive $Driver -Id "mainForm-RaiseUser2Display"
Send-SeKeys -Element $User -Keys "My user name here"

#THIS IS WHERE I'M HAVING TROUBLE
$dropDown = $Driver.FindElementByCssSelector(".dropdownItem:nth-child(2)");
Invoke-SeClick -Element $dropDown
```

Here's the HTML for the page I am testing, plus link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mYHqApsGue1IE-Zm9Eqwz2aiXKk7jIO2/view:

```
<div class="dropdown" id="mainForm-RaiseUser2-Dropdown" style="height: 503px; left: 299px; top: 171px; width: 973px; display: none;">
    <div class="dropdownContent" style="height: 502.5px;"></div>
    <div class="dropdownFooter"></div>
</div>
```

And here's the output I get:

```
Exception calling "FindElementByCssSelector" with "1" argument(s): "no such 
element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css 
selector","selector":".dropdownItem:nth-child(2)"}
  (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.90)"
At C:\Scripts\SeleniumWebAutomation.ps1:36 char:1
+ $dropDown = $Driver.FindElementByCssSelector(".dropdownItem:nth-child ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoSuchElementException

Invoke-SeClick : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Element' because it is null.
At C:\Scripts\SeleniumWebAutomation.ps1:37 char:25
+ Invoke-SeClick -Element $dropDown
+                         ~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Invoke-SeClick], ParameterBindingV 
   alidationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Invok 
   e-SeClick
```

Comment: We need HTML at least some part around element, to check the selector otherwise we can't help u.

Comment: Looks like your selector cannot locate an element on the page. Could you post some HTML from the page source you are testing? It is hard to determine what might be wrong with the selector without seeing page source.

Comment: Based on Exception, some thinks wrong in your element you have pass in the code, share the DOM file that will help us to resolve your problem. I'm not sure why you have css, don't it have an ID?

Comment: If it has an ID, I can't find it.  It pulls up names after you type one in, and there are LOTS of user names (Multiple pages)

Comment: How's this?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mYHqApsGue1IE-Zm9Eqwz2aiXKk7jIO2/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @lazyindfw Are you trying to click the dropdown itself, or are you trying to click the names the appear after you type one in?

Comment: The name that appears would be ideal.

Comment: The HTML sample you provided through Google Docs looks like the form itself, but I can't see anything that appears after you expand the dropdown. Could you expand this dropdown with names, and get the HTML for the names that appear? I've added a suggestion below, but might not work without the expanded dropdown HTML.

Comment: I got this for an xpath when trying to use an object spy when I had the dropdown selected:

//span[@id='control-wrapper-mainForm-RaiseUser2']/span[@class='dropdownFrame dropdownFrameFocus']

Comment: The above path looks fine, but will not select a specific name -- you will need the text of the name you want to select included in there somewhere. Depending on your browser (I use chrome), get the page into the state you want (dropdown expanded). Then right click on the dropdown and do 'Inspect Element', or hit F12 to open devtools. This should display the HTML page source.

Comment: Found it!
It starts with this:
<div class="dropdownContent" style="height: 502.5px; overflow-y: auto;"><div class="dropdownItem" value="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" params="{}">[Clear selection]</div>

Then goes on to list names, here's mine below:

<div class="dropdownItem dropdownSelectedItem" value="fcbe6ca8-1ab7-4083-ae17-075139afa876" params="{}">mylastname, myfirstname</div>

Do I invoke it somehow by value?

Comment: @lazyindfw This helps a bit. Based on this HTML you just provided, I updated my answer below with something that might work. I'm still slightly confused on how to expand this dropdown, so I assumed it was a regular dropdown menu which gets expanded when you click on it. If that's not correct, just let me know and I can try to adjust my answer.

Comment: Ok, I'm making progress.. It's a dropdown list, and when you start typing a name it starts narrowing in on your name. 

If you type your full name (last, first) the only two items in the dropdown will be
[Clear selection] and YourLastName, YourFirstName. It's also a lot of nested classes. 

Like this: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1w22O9eLwak7WSWbLflb0MlsolTJFZYln  (That's from when I used the Chrome inspect option)

Answer (score 2):

Edited to reflect comments you added to the original post relating to dropdown & dropdown options selectors.

Given the following HTML for a dropdown menu:

```
<div class="dropdownContent" style="height: 502.5px; overflow-y: auto;"><div class="dropdownItem" value="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" params="{}">
```

And the following HTML for a dropdown menu item:

```
<div class="dropdownItem dropdownSelectedItem" value="fcbe6ca8-1ab7-4083-ae17-075139afa876" params="{}">mylastname, myfirstname</div>
```

It looks like you want to expand a dropdown by clicking it, then click a dropdown option containing text lastname, firstname. Replacing your last two lines of code, here's how I would do that:

```
# First expand the dropdown
$dropDown = $Driver.FindElementByXPath("//div[@class='dropdownContent']");
Invoke-SeClick -Element $dropDown

# Not sure on the syntax but you may need to Invoke WebDriverWait here, before you can click element.

# Click the desired option
$dropdownOption = $Driver.FindElementByXPath("//div[text()='mylastname, myfirstname']");
Invoke-SeClick -Element $dropdownOption
```

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party but I found out this is working for me, probably works for you too.

```
$Value = '2'
$Option = Find-SeElement -Driver $Driver -XPath "/html/body/div/select"

$SelectElement = [OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.SelectElement]::new($Option)
$SelectElement.SelectByValue($Value)
```

My HTML element looks like this and will select Watermelon with the script above...

```
<select class="custom-select">
      <option selected="">Open this select menu</option>
      <option value="1">Banana</option>
      <option value="2">Watermelon</option>
      <option value="3">Mango</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, Christine!  I dug into xpath usage a lot after this.  After pulling my hair out and trying different things (including ditching the selenium module i found, incorporating Firebug, etc)  I was able to get it to work by adding a Start-Sleep (wait) statement.  It just wasn't finding the drop down because I wasn't waiting for it to pop up I guess.

```
Start-sleep -s 2
$ChromeDriver.FindElementByClassName("dropdownSelectedItem").click()
```

Now it works!  Joy!